# Dataframe Iterate items in one column and store it into array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe shown in below.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

And I want to make it like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | {1, 3, 5} |
| B | {2, 4, 6} |

I can use .T to rotate the table and know .columns to set table header, but i don't know how to combine items in a column into an array.

Besides, is it possible the array in deltalake?

Comment: what have you tried so far, and what material have you read prior to asking?
Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section on how to ask good to get better responds

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes I had already tried and cannot find a solution. Otherwise, I will not ask about this problem here, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert DataFrame to dictionaries by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and then create new `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict('list').items(), columns=['Key','Value'])
print (df)
  Key      Value
0   A  [1, 3, 5]
1   B  [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to combine the items in a column into an array in a Pandas DataFrame. Here is one way to do it:

import pandas as pd

create the dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 5], 'B': [2, 4, 6]})
```

use the `groupby` and `apply` methods to combine the items in each column into an array

```py
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
```

rename the columns of the dataframe

```py
df.columns = ['Key', 'Value']
```

print the result

```
>>> print(df)
    Key       Value
0   A  [1, 3, 5]
1   B  [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: I got an array [[1], [3], [5]], [[2], [4], [6]], not sure if the value inside the array have also become an array as well...